# Matab: copy certain rows from text files to another file

Tags: matlab, append, text-files, extract

I have 300 files which have similar structure.
I am interested in rows 82-nd and 90-th in each file.

The 82-nd row is:
span 1 =     -0.193,      **1.980**

The 90-th row is:
span 9 =      0.000,    **557.000**

I would like to copy the last number from rows 82 and 90 next to each other, also append those values from each file, like so:

output-file:

**1.980** **557.000**
2.568 687.500
1.158 496.030
............

Can someone help me? It would also be ok, if I could copy each 82 and 90 row to new file and the others under that, like so:
span 1 =     -0.193,      1.980
span 9 =      0.000,    557.000

span 1 =     -0.193,      2.568
span 9 =      0.000,    687.500

span 1 =     -0.193,      1.158
span 9 =      0.000,    496.030
.....

Comment: This sounds like a perfect job for shell commands like `sed`. Do you strictly need to process these files within MATLAB, without using system programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) with `headerlines` to jump to the desired rows.

The format spec `span %d = %f, %f` tells `textscan` to give us the span id in `{1}` and span values in `{2}` and `{3}`. It assumes lines 82 and 90 are formatted strictly as described in the question (i.e., `span x = y, z`).

This code scans 1 line twice (first at line 82, then at 90). Alternatively you could also scan 9 lines once (lines 82-90 in one go) and then index into those 9 lines.

```matlab
row1 = 82; % row of span 1
row9 = 90; % row of span 9

files = dir('/path/to/data/*.dat'); % change to real path
result = nan(length(files), 2); % preallocate

for file = files
    fpath = fullfile(file.folder, file.name);
    fid = fopen(fpath);
    
    format = 'span %d = %f, %f'; % assume `span x = y, z`
    lines = 1 % scan 1 line twice (we could also scan 9 lines at once and index the output)
    span1 = textscan(fid, format, lines, 'headerlines', row1 - 1);
    span9 = textscan(fid, format, lines, 'headerlines', row9 - row1);
    
    if (span1{1} == 1) && (span9{1} == 9) % verify span id
        result(1, :) = [span1{3} span9{3}];
    end
    
    fclose(fid);
end

csvwrite('result.csv', result);
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know how to modify this code to work with all dat-files (*.dat) in a folder? I have 300 files which all are formatted similarly.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the answer with one way to read files from disk. Note the lines with `files = dir(...)` and `fpath = fullfile(...)`